# vim ultisnips reactivate snipet

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I'm a vim/ultisnips newbie trying to be more efficient when writing and coding. I've successfully installed the ultisnips plugin and it works so far.

My question is: is it possible to "reactivate" a snippet after it has been filled? The documentation says:

> UltiSnips will only map the jump triggers while a snippet is active to
>   interfere as little as possible with other mappings.

But actually I would like to reactivate a snippet from time to time in order to efficiently jump between the placeholders while updating/modifying the snippet content.

Any idea how this can be done?